# Vue.js/Vuex Login: [vuex] unknown action type: postLogin.

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm fairly new to Vuejs but more so with Vuex - I understand the basics of Vue and Vuex. I am struggling to get my login working. This is the error I'm getting:

```
[vuex] unknown action type: postLogin.
```

I want to successfully hit the api. I already created the user on the backend (with django). So I can login in via the admin portal. Trying to login using vue frontend via apis/axios.

Here I have my component.vue code:

```
             <v-card-text>
               <v-form @submit.prevent="postLogin(email, password)">
                 <v-text-field v-model="email" prepend-icon="person" name="login" label="Login" type="text"></v-text-field>
                 <v-text-field v-model="password" prepend-icon="lock" name="password" label="Password" id="password" type="password"></v-text-field>
                 <v-card-actions>
                   <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                   <v-btn type ='submit' color="primary">Login</v-btn>
                 </v-card-actions>
               </v-form>
             </v-card-text>
```

Here is my auth.js store action:

```
const actions = {
  postLogin (context, payload) {
    return axios.post('/api/users/login/', payload)
      .then(response => {})
      .catch(e => {
        context.commit('setAuthError', true)
        console.log(e)
      })
  },
```

Here is my component script trying to call the action:

```
<script>
import postLogin from '@/store/modules/auth'

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      drawer: null,
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }),
    props: {
      source: String
    },
    methods: {
      postLogin (email,password) {
        this.$store
          .dispatch('postLogin', {email, password}).then(()=> this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'}))
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have tried everything, please help me.

Comment: What is happening now and what do you actually want to happen?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: [vuex] unknown action type: postLogin. I want to successfully hit the api. I already created the user on the backend (with django). So I can login in via the admin portal. Trying to login using vue frontend via apis/axios.

Comment: please share your store code

Comment: The dispatch call and action appear to be correct (except for your logic) so I have a feeling that you don't have Vuex properly setup.

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim My store code is in the question under auth.js.

Comment: @StevenB. What is wrong with my logic? I think you might be right about the setup. I will go through it tonight again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your router will route to the dashboard whether the login throws an error or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your `vuex` is using modules. If you set up [namespacing](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) with them (i.e., you declare `namespaced: true` in your module), then your `action` is no longer on the global namespace. You have to adjust your code to dispatch to `auth/postLogin` instead:

`this.$store
     .dispatch('auth/postLogin', {email, password})
     .then(() => this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'}));`

The above will work, assuming that when you register this namespaced module to your `root` store, you also name it `auth`. If you name it to something else, you will have to adjust your `dispatch()` call accordingly:

```js
// inside your src/store/index.js
import auth from './modules/auth';

...
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  ...
  modules: {
    auth,        // <-- call dispatch('auth/postLogin', {email, password})
    auth: auth,  // <-- call dispatch('auth/postLogin', {email, password})
    authen: auth // <-- call dispatch('authen/postLogin', {email, password})
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It turns out that I had a index.js and a store.js which caused ambiguity within the application.

Comment: @WernerKotze I see. Glad you sorted it out. :)